# Running a Python Script on my website?

Tags: python, execution, cgi-bin

I have a website with miniwebhost.com, which supports python. I want to have a page that runs one of my text based games I have made on Python. So, how would I go about doing it? I know I have to make it executable and something about a cgi-bin(which I have). Put your answer in clear steps please.

Site is: www.rosshudson.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Python web applications are often hooked to the web server (e.g. Apache httpd) using the [WSGI](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) module. Note that your app need to handle the HTTP requests correctly either by using a framework (like Django) or the BaseHttpServer, BaseHttpRequestHandler from the standard library.